# Simple edit strings in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have 2 strings, A and B. A contains "HelloHowAreYou". B contains "Bingo". I want to replace string A with string B resulting to "BingoHowAreYou". Any tips on how to do this? Even a keyword is suffice.

I know this is kinda newbie, but i dont want to hunt all msdn doc just to find this simple things. As i said, a simple guide/keyword pointing to the right direction is enough.

Edit:

Assuming i dont know the contents of the strings. can i just use the replace? Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: Note: C# strings are immutable, so strictly speaking you can't *edit* them, you have to create a new string (even if you assign the new string to an existing variable).

Comment: Everyone here is doing some wild guessing on how to determine which part of A should be replaced (which you did not specify!)

Comment: sorry doc. my bad. i appreciate all the fast reply. hence the free votes. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately, you don't need to hunt down *all* of MSDN... just [the String class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx).

As others have said, [`String.Replace(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) is probably what you're looking for:

```
string a = "HelloHowAreYou";
string b = "Bingo";
string c = a.Replace("Hello", b); // Now the value of c is "BingoHowAreYou"
```

Alternatively, if you're trying to just replace the first characters of `a` with the same number of characters in `b`, something like this would do instead, using `Substring` and string concatenation:

```
string c = b.Length >= a.Length ? b : b + a.Substring(b.Length);
```

(Depending on exactly what you want to do when `b` is longer than `a` of course.)

A few things worth knowing though:

- This is a good example of *library* functionality - so you won't find a C# keyword for it. While some C# keywords *do* interact with the library (e.g. `using` statements that know about the `IDisposable` type) most of the time, if you're interested in something which sounds like a library feature, you should be looking in the library documentation rather than looking for a keyword.
- Strings are *immutable*: `String.Replace` doesn't change the existing string - it returns a *new* string with the appropriate result. Some other types follow the same pattern - in particular value types such as `DateTime` are typically immutable, so `DateTime.AddDays` doesn't change the existing value, but returns a new value.
- It's worth getting used to looking through MSDN. You're likely to do it a *lot*, so having a look through the string class now would be good practice.

Comment: By keyword i mean keyword use to google. Thanks. will report back.

Comment: Looks like the "alternative" way is what the OP is after, so +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

```
string C = A.Replace("Hello", "Bingo");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string a = "HelloHowAreYou";
string b = "Bingo";

string result = a.Replace( "Hello", b );
```

This should do what you describe, it returns a new string with "BingoHowAreYou"

[MSDN article on Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
string a = "HelloHowAreYou";
string b = "Bingo"
a = a.Replace("Hello", b); // will replace a to "BingoHowAreYou"
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

[String.Replace Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
 A=A.Replace("Hello",B)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = "HelloHowAreYou";
var b = "Bingo";
var c = a.Replace("Hello", b);
```